# Why django File Class set DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 64 * 2 ** 10?

Tags: python, django

I am reading the django [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/core/files/base/) on the `django.core.files.base`

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class File(FileProxyMixin):
    DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 64 * 2 ** 10
```

why the default CHUNK_SIZE to 65536? Any reason for that?

Comment: an reasonable size. nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2070) has some discussion that might be informative and that lead to [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/d725cc9734272f867d41f7236235c28b3931a1b2). The short version is that it is a reasonable size that keeps too much of the file from being in memory at a time, since you can just handle a chunk at a time with the generator File.chunks().